# Cryptography Hazmat Primitives Asymmetric Public Key Verification Throw Me an Error. Why is That? Python

Tags: python, cryptography, signature, public-key-encryption

I have created a PrivateKey-PublicKey pair and I signed a message with a signature just like this:

```
private_key = ec.generate_private_key(ec.SECP256K1(), default_backend())
public_key = private_key.public_key()
public_key = public_key.public_bytes(encoding=Encoding.DER, 
                              format=PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)

message = b'caramel pie'

signature = private_key.sign(message, ec.ECDSA(hashes.SHA256()))
public_key.verify(signature, message, ec.ECDSA(hashes.SHA256()))
```

However, when I try to verify the signiture it gives me back an error like:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [228], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 public_key.verify(signature, data, ec.ECDSA(hashes.SHA256()))

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'verify'
```

Why is that? What am I doing wrong? How to verify the message? Anyone that could help here?

Comment: You are overwriting `public_key` (line 2) with the exported key (line 3)! Either use the original `public_key` (i.e. apply a different name for the exported key) or, if you want to use the exported key, you have to import it first.

Comment: Caramba, it worked !!! Thanks!!! When I use only the public_key1, I am able to verify now. May questian is how to import the exported key from line 3 if I have to? Can you give an example please?

Comment: Since the exported key is DER encoded, the import is feasible with `serialization.load_der_public_key(...)`.